# Convert the CSV of an item into a mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a csv file for each item in my store.
Each csv contains the sales of the related item:
date, sales,...

I would like to import each csv into a related document:

```
    item{
    title: string,
    description: string,
    sales: [{date1, sales1},{date2, sales2},... ]
    }
```

I would prefer a solution involving node.js if someone thinks about doing a loop.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use mongoimport. If you cannot accept the answer provided below, could you edit the question to explain why it's not acceptable? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you should try using mongoimport:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

It is part of Mongodb and you can run it on command prompt.

It will send information to any mongo db you want.